# Terasort error : Requested more partitions than input keys (1 > 0)

Tags: mapreduce, benchmarking, hadoop2, terasort, teragen

I am working on Hadoop benchmarking and working with teragen and tera sort tool for the same.

The teragen tool is working fine, for which i am using the following command:

```
hadoop jar /Users/karan.verma/Documents/backups/h/hadoop-2.6.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar  teragen -Dmapreduce.job.maps=100 1t random-data1
```

and gives the following output on console:

```
17/10/03 17:19:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1507026170114_0005 completed successfully
17/10/03 17:19:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=10661490
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=8594
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=400
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=200
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=100
        Other local map tasks=100
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=1089472
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=1089472
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1089472
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1115619328
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=0
        Map output records=0
        Input split bytes=8594
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=9690
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=11115954176
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
```

And following this when i execute the terasort tool using the following command:

```
hadoop jar  /Users/karan.verma/Documents/backups/h/hadoop-2.6.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar  terasort random-data1 sorted-data
```

i got the following error:

```
17/10/03 17:20:10 INFO terasort.TeraSort: starting
17/10/03 17:20:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/10/03 17:20:11 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 100
Spent 168ms computing base-splits.
Spent 2ms computing TeraScheduler splits.
Computing input splits took 172ms
Sampling 10 splits of 100
Making 1 from 0 sampled records
17/10/03 17:20:11 ERROR terasort.TeraSort: Requested more partitions than input keys (1 > 0)
```

Any help, why is this happening? Is there anything which i'm missing in configuration part?

Comment: Please suggest any solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of the teragen command because output file generated may be empty. You would get this error if the input data size is 0.